# Slow reading of mp3 files with NAudio

Tags: c#, stream, streaming, naudio

I would like to know how I can efficiently read local mp3 files with NAudio?
I tried several methods to read mp3 and play it back using a `WaveOut` but it is very slow sometimes.
For my current test case I took several mp3 files with filesizes between 80MB and 180MB.
First I used a `Mp3FileReader`:

```
myWaveOut.Init(new Mp3FileReader("test.mp3"));
```

Then I used a `FileStream` and passed it to an `Mp3FileReader`.

```
FileStream stream = File.OpenRead("test.mp3");
myWaveOut.Init(new Mp3FileReader(stream));
```

Same problems...
Further I used variatons of these (e.g. different buffer sizes/readers).

I inspected my taskmanager and everytime I read a file it seems that the reader reads the whole file before playing it. E.g. it took like 10-20 seconds to play one of my files. According to my taskmanager the file was loaded with 5.6 - 6.5 MB/s during this time. So in this time period the whole file could have been loaded.

Am I doing something wrong?
Are there more efficient ways to load larger files and stream them?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's because `Mp3FileReader` creates a Table of Contents up front allowing it to report the duration, and reposition accurately. The easiest way to avoid this is just use `MediaFoundationReader` to play MP3 files instead, or else, just make a very simple MP3FileReader class of your own, parsing out MP3Frames and decoding with AcmMp3FrameDecompressor. Maybe a future version of NAudio will make the TOC generation optional.

Comment: To add to this - WM ASF reader is also known to be reading MP3 files: one more option to choose from, when it comes to standard offerings.